# SQL running slow when executed thru java

Tags: java, oracle10g, sqlperformance

I am trying to execute a query in oracle db.
When i try to run thru SQLTools the query is executing in 2 seconds
and when i run the same query thru JAVA it is exectuting in more than a minute.

I am using a hint `/*+ordered use_nl (a, b)*/`

I am using ojdbc6.jar Is it because of any JARS? 
Please help whats causing this?

Comment: A simple example could be useful. Also, are you measuring just the time for the query or some sort of JVM startup time as well?

Comment: I am measuring the time of the query

Comment: hints are irrelevant unless you post the query, and perhaps the explain plan for both the unhinted and hinted versions of the query.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle 9i or later, database engine can tune SQL automatically, few case need to specify hints.

How do you run query in Java, repeat to run in loop? use parameter? prepare before execute?

Comment: I am running thru preparedstatement

Comment: Do you measure one minute time in which statement?

1. preparestatement()
2. execute()
3. while (resultSet.next())
4.     // do something

cost one minute in which step?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **profile your Java application** to identify where in the Java code before or after the SQL execution that overhead time is being spent.

Some profiling tools that you can use for that are: [YourKit](http://freshmeat.net/projects/yjp/), [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html?gclid=CMf81Onhxp8CFQk65QodMiqtzw) and [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) (this one is a command line tool).

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? You really need to run a profiler to find out why it takes a minute to run the SQL via your Java app. I  doubt that it is in Oracle that it is taking over a minute, since it only takes 2 seconds from SQL Tools.